# Enforcing car free Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, vehicles-transportation, knas-penalty

Personally, I really enjoy in Israel that religious neighbourhoods block car traffic on the Shabbat. (I mean by legal means and road signs as well.) It is much of a relief after the chaos and the traffic jams of the weekdays. Yet, there are always a few guys, who think it is a good idea to drive a car in such zones during the Shabbat, while it is quite evident that they wouldn't be allowed to do that from a religious perspective. Therefore, I was wondering, what could be a halakhically acceptable way to enforce the regulation? Since the ban is only for the Shabbat, one may not hire guards only for the Shabbat (see [Orach Chayim 244:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%93_%D7%90)). I'm not sure either how could an automated system work based on the optical recognition of number plates. What could be a feasible solution?

Comment: There are plenty of legitimate reasons to be driving a car on Shabbat. Without delving into each driver's personal life, how are you going to allow those and forbid others?

Comment: @magicker72 I suppose you could simply tell the guard or the system, whether you had anything to do there. Most cars are just crossing the zone, because it's shorter, many of them are sherut or similar.

Comment: Give them a ticket with a hefty fine. There’s basis in Halacha for Takanas Ha’ir to levy fines and the like